# Nothing working when trying to run C programs?

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I have been trying to use Cygwin64 to compile and run C programs. I have been trying to run a simple Hello World program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!");
}
```

And in Cygwin, I have been typing the following command:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

Followed by

```
./hello.exe
```

After that, there is simply no output, and I receive a new prompt.
Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: are you sure gcc is adding a `.exe` extension?

Comment: I tried adding inputs like that where the program has to stop, but the same thing happens, I receive a new prompt. I also see that gcc has created a new file called hello.exe in the same directory.

Comment: You executable name is just `hello`, try this:

    `./hello`

Comment: I also get the same result for that input

Comment: in windows you can direct run a program on present directory like "hello" no need to give "./" .or may be you should try like this "gcc -o hello.exe hello.c" and than "hello.exe" if it is not working than there must be other problem

Comment: That does not work either. I tried many different things, and nothing seems to produce any output at all. I have tried reinstalling Cygwin several times as well.

Comment: Try adding a `\n` after `"Hello world!"` i.e `"Hello world!\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Gcc don't give `.exe` extention for output executable file. You are giving `gcc -o hello hello.c` command then it generates executable with name `hello (not hello.exe)`. If you don't give any name for output file, it generates executable file with name `a.out`

Comment: Even when I input gcc -o hello.exe hello.c and then run ./hello.exe I still get no output.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the prompt printed after the execution of the program is printed by first returning the cursor to column 0. This is then overwriting the "Hello World!" message you've printed. You should probably add a `"\r\n"` to your `printf` call as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\r\n");
}
```

This will move the cursor to the next line before exiting, so that the prompt is printed on the next line instead.

Comment: Why "\r\n" and not just "\n"? Please justify.

Comment: Nope...still no output

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to pause your program.

Can be done with a get(), scanf()
Also you should do a return 0; at the end of your code